# How to Disabled Master Form After Search Button?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, master-pages

**[image: After Click Search Button Want to Disable Master Page Forms except Books information]
[image: On the Top Master Page Form Want to Disable all Except book Inforamtion]

This my Search Button Code I want to Disabled Master Page After Search Signup**

```
try
            {
                signUp signUp = new signUp();
                signUp.Username = txtUserName.Text;
                Session["user"] = signUp.Authentication();
                Response.Redirect("BooksInformation.aspx");
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblOutput.Text = ex.Message;
            }
```

Comment: What you mean by `Disabled` Master Page?

Comment: Please Check my Second image. There are five forms on the top include student, Issue Book, Library Information I want to disable those after signup from search button @Arsen

Comment: @Arsen it means after search books sign up all top form disabled so student can only search books

Comment: You want to make these five buttons disabled or just to hide them?

Comment: Yes Want to Hide or Disable but this is not button this is href = " Student.aspx" @Arsen

Comment: Can you provide these five links code here?

Comment: <li class ="navigation_first_time"><a href="MainSlider.aspx"><i class="far fa-plus-square"; style="color:black; font-size:40px;"></i> Main Form</b></a></li>               
 <li >  <a href ="LibraryInformation.aspx"> <i class="far fa-plus-square"; style="color:black; font-size:40px;">Library Information</b></a></li>                                                     
 <li>  <a href ="BooksInformation.aspx"> <i class="fas fa-search"; style="color:black; font-size:40px;"></i>&nbspBooks Information </b></a><br /></li>
                     <li>  <a href ="Studentss.aspx">  @Arsen

Comment: @Arsen this is three link code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose in the Master page you've got something like this:

```
<a href="Student.aspx">Students</a>
```

add `runat="server"` and `id` property for the tag

```
<a href="Student.aspx" id="studentLink" runat="server">Students</a>
```

Then in the `Page_Load` event of the `BooksInformation.aspx` make sure the user is logged in and hide the links:

```
var studentLink = Master.FindControl("studentLink") as HtmlControl;
studentLink.Visible = false;
```

Comment: When we write this code it shows error in html control and .aspx.visible                                 
      ```  var studentLink = Master.FindControl("LibraryInformation.aspx") as HtmlControl;
            LibraryInformation.aspx.Visible = false;  ```

Comment: You should remove `.aspx` from `id` value. As I mentioned in the answer add `id` property to your link `<a href="Student.aspx" id="studentLink" runat="server">Students</a>`

Comment: Great Programmer Thank you soo much for your effort..

Comment: One Issue appear after putting ID it is hide but not running from different login

Comment: What part exactly does not work from different login?

Comment: WHEN I add id="studentLink" it will hide but from different login Students.aspx not running

Comment: [<a href="Student.aspx" id="studentLink" runat="server">Students</a>] @Arsen  Student.aspx not running

Comment: The link should work for any login, do you have some code behind which is responsible for redirection to the Student.aspx

Comment: And what you mean by *not running*? You click on it and nothing happens?

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Studentss.aspx

Comment: from different login it will show this error after clicking students.aspx @arsen

Comment: First of all remove double **s** in the end of **Studentss.aspx**. If your .aspx page name is `Students.aspx` link should be `<a href="Students.aspx" id="studentLink" runat="server">Students</a>`

Comment: Sir My Aspx page name is Studentss.aspx without id and runat server it is running perfectly when I add id its not running @Arsen

Comment: Can you provide any source so I can send you screenshots

Comment: You can update your question with the new data and screenshots